# Identify the size of the address assigned to the pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, strlen

In my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZ 256   //arbitrary value

typedef char text_t;
text_t text[SIZ];


text_t *create_text()
{
    text_t *c;
    strcpy(text,"");
    c= text;
    return c;
}


int main()
{

text_t *point_to_text;

point_to_text=create_text();

printf("length of the returned pointer")

    return 0;

}
```

I want to assign point_to_text a string of length zero. I used `strcpy(text,"");` to copy an empty string. How can I show that length of the text is zero in this case. Also, if I use `strcpy(text,"abc");` , how can I show the length is 3 in this case?

Comment: Sidenote: In C, if function takes has no parameters, you should use `void` instead of empty parameter list: `text_t *create_text(void)`. Also, `main` function has only 2 standard forms on hosted environments: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char * argv [])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
  length =  strlen(point_to_text);
```

String Literals in C means a ASCII character codes stored at consecutive memory location terminated by null char(\0).

`strlen()` expects the input to be a pointer to a constant char string terminated by null char(0 or '\0'). The function returns length of the string excluding null char.

Comment: while this code block might answer the question you should try to include relevant explanation in order to improve your answer. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) on the returned pointer `point_to_text`.

Assuming you're returning a proper *string* [i.e., null-terminated], `strlen()` will give you the length of the string, i.e., the number of valid elements present in the *string* (excluding the null terminator).

You can do

```
printf("length of the returned string is %zu\n", strlen(point_to_text));
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t` which probaby is `unsigned long`. POSIX defines `zu` for `size_t`.

Comment: I have noticed that it returns unsigned long. Why does it return UL and not integer , as I am assuming length should return an integer, And is %zu represent unsigned long or %ld ? why do we use %zu?